# Apache Alias Question

Tags: apache, location, alias

Is it possible to have an Apache Server evaluate its Aliases before it evaluates its Locations?

```
Alias /foo /bar
<Location "/bar">
SetHandler None
</Location>
```

So that the above code will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it will, but based on your example you are not using alias correctly.  It handles URL to file/directory mapping, which is why your location directive is not applying.

This is what I think you're looking for:

```
Alias /foo /var/www/foo
Alias /bar /var/www/foo
<Location "/bar">
    SetHandler None
</Location>
```